# Error accessing an attribute of a class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
class chainlist:

    def ___init__(self):
        self.chain = [6 ,7]
        self.create_block(proof=1)
blockchain  = chainlist()

print(chainlist.chain)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(chainlist.chain)
AttributeError: class chainlist has no attribute 'chain'
```

Comment: uh... there's a couple problems here...

Comment: Why are you creating a class instance, if you are not using it ?

Comment: Because he's creating a blockchain. Can't you see?

Comment: sorry i tried with blockchain.chain plese edit the code

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. `init` needs to be surrounded by double underscore.
2. An instance variable needs to be accessed via the class instance, not the class itself.

Try this instead:

```
class chainlist:

    def __init__(self):
        self.chain = [6 ,7]

blockchain = chainlist()

print(blockchain.chain)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `print(blockchain.chain)` not `chainlist.chain`. Here is an example how you can access different variables in a class.

```
class chainlist:
    myvar = [0, 1] # class variable shared by all instances
    def __init__(self):
        self.chain = [6 ,7]  # instance variable unique to each instance

blockchain = chainlist()
print(blockchain.chain)
print(chainlist.myvar)
```

Please read this ['Class and Instance Variables'](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) to have clear understanding.

Comment: i tried with  blockchain.chain edit the code i got the same error